# Don't store principal with Google login

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-signin, google-authentication

We are using .NET Core 3.1 and Google Authentication. This is the code that we have currently:

**Startup.cs:**

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
    {
        googleOptions.ClientId = "CLIENT_ID"
        googleOptions.ClientSecret = "CLIENT_SECRET"
    })
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Error/403";
    });
```

**AccountController.cs:**

```cs
public class AccountController : BaseController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult SignInGoogle()
    {
        return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = Url.Action(nameof(SignInReturn))
        }, GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult SignInReturn()
    {
        // User's information is in the User property of the controller. We don't want that.
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

When users visit `/Account/SignInGoogle`, they are redirected to Google sign in page. Once they log in successfully, they are redirected back to `/Account/SignInReturn`. If I place a breakpoint there, I can see that claims are set inside `User` property.

Is it possible that we somehow receive user information (name, surname, email) in `SignInReturn` without the user principal being set in `User` field? We don't want Google middleware to perform the actual log in (setting `User` principal). We just want to verify that users are able to sign in to their company Google account and then proceed with custom login logic once we receive the email that they used to sign in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After receiving the user in `SignInReturn` action, you can easily implement your custom login, even logout the user, such as the following code:

```
 await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
```

Or to receive user information, do the following and sign in again after the necessary checks:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> SignInReturn()
{
   var authenticateResult = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

   if (!authenticateResult.Succeeded)
   {
       return Unauthorized();
   }

   string email = authenticateResult.Principal?.FindFirst(s => s.Type == ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;

   string giveName = authenticateResult.Principal?.FindFirst(s => s.Type == ClaimTypes.GivenName)?.Value;

   string surName = authenticateResult.Principal?.FindFirst(s => s.Type == ClaimTypes.Surname)?.Value;

   string fullName = authenticateResult.Principal?.FindFirst(s => s.Type == ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;

   //Check the user exist in the database by email or other items, and signin the user again
   //await HttpContext.SignInAsync();
}
```